# Error: Querying [object Object] failed: wasm execution failed with error

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I am having trouble resolving the error.
I am now trying to get a list of product data stored in a map in vector form.

```rust
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
#[serde(crate = "near_sdk::serde")]
pub struct Room {
    room_id: U64,
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    price: U128,
    owner: AccountId,
}

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Rooms {
    pub rooms: UnorderedMap<U64, Room>,
}

impl Default for Rooms {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            rooms: UnorderedMap::new(b"r".to_vec()),
        }
    }
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl Rooms {
    pub fn set_room(
        &mut self,
        name: String,
        image: String,
        description: String,
        location: String,
        price: U128,
    ) -> U64 {
        let timestamp = env::block_timestamp();
        let convert_timestamp: U64 = timestamp.into();
    
        let account_id = env::signer_account_id();

        self.rooms.insert(
            &convert_timestamp.clone(),
            &Room {
                room_id: convert_timestamp,
                name,
                image,
                description,
                location,
                price,
                owner: account_id,
            },
        );
        convert_timestamp
    }

    pub fn get_room(&self, room_id: U64) -> Room {
        self.rooms.get(&room_id).expect("No Room")
    }

    pub fn get_rooms(&self) -> Vec<Room> {
        Vec::from_iter(self.rooms.values())
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I call `get_rooms`.

`$ near view dev-1658072311649-16892075058144 get_rooms`

```bash
    View call: dev-1658072311649-16892075058144.get_rooms()
    An error occured
    Error: Querying [object Object] failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: "Cannot deserialize element" })).
    {
      "block_hash": "54p5pS8xrzi7GWzv5YcgpNT33f7RqYdR7sUzHaTdzsqf",
      "block_height": 95181885,
      "error": "wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: \"Cannot deserialize element\" }))",
      "logs": []
    }
        at JsonRpcProvider.query (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:123:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async Account.viewFunction (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:366:24)
        at async exports.callViewFunction (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:98:48)
        at async Object.handler (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9)
    TypedError: Querying [object Object] failed: wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: "Cannot deserialize element" })).
    {
      "block_hash": "54p5pS8xrzi7GWzv5YcgpNT33f7RqYdR7sUzHaTdzsqf",
      "block_height": 95181885,
      "error": "wasm execution failed with error: FunctionCallError(HostError(GuestPanic { panic_msg: \"Cannot deserialize element\" }))",
      "logs": []
    }
        at JsonRpcProvider.query (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:123:19)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async Account.viewFunction (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:366:24)
        at async exports.callViewFunction (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:98:48)
        at async Object.handler (/Users/user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9) {
      type: 'UntypedError',
      context: undefined
    }
```

Why do I get an error about serialization only when I get the product information as a vector?

All other functions work fine.
[image]
If you know the cause and solution, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested your code and it worked fine for me. You can try calling the method in `dev-1658147947569-44192518546131`.

Make sure you are using the latest near-sdk (4.0), and that you are importing everything from the right place:

```rust
use near_sdk::borsh::{self, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use near_sdk::{near_bindgen, env, AccountId, collections::{UnorderedMap}};
use near_sdk::json_types::{U64, U128};
use near_sdk::serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
```